# How to set an array to empty array when using prevState in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using prev state to append the array and I need to set the whole array to an empty array on the button clicked. I tried using setArray({}) but it doesn't work. how to completely set the array to an empty array on button click

```
import React, {useState,useEffect} from 'react'

function testFunction() {

    const [features, setFeatures] = useState({});

    const add = (key,value) => {
        setFeatures((prevFeatures)=>({...prevFeatures,[key]: value}));
    }

    const clear =() =>{
        setFeatures({});
    }

    return (
        <div>
            
            <div>
                <select onChange={(event)=>add(event.target.name,event.target.value)}>
                    <option name="opt1" value="val1">Value1</option>
                    <option name="opt2" value="val2">Value2</option>
                    <option name="opt3" value="val3">Value3</option>
                    <option name="opt4" value="val4">Value4</option>
                    <option name="opt5" value="val5">Value5</option>
                </select>
            </div>

            <button type="reset" value="reset" onClick={()=>clear}>Reset</button>

        </div>
    )
}
export default testFunction
```

Comment: where is the features state?

Comment: There's no feacture state and probably `prevFeatures` is undefined too. You should have something like `const [feature, setFeature] = useState([]);` and whenever you want to set that feature state to an empty array do something like `setFeature([])`. The code is unclear atm tho.

Comment: @İlker a small mistake was there. now updated

Comment: @EdgardoRodríguez a small mistake was there. now updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must execute your function `clear` because in your code you are only passing the declared function.

```
<button type="reset" value="reset" onClick={()=>clear}>Reset</button>
```

`onClick={()=>clear}` must be replaced for `onClick={()=>clear()}` or `onClick={clear}`

Answer (score 2):

First of all you didn't initialize your state as an array? So first let's do that;

`const [features, setFeatures] = useState([])`

also your functions should be like this;

```
 const add = (key,value) => {
        setFeatures((prevFeatures)=>([...prevFeatures, {[key]: value} ])); // key, value added to array of Objects
    }

    const clear =() =>{
        setFeatures([]); // setting empty array
    }
```

also you should call clear function ;

```
<button type="reset" value="reset" onClick={()=>clear()}>Reset</button>
```

Comment: @NathinduDias well I'm updating the answer